# How to iterate over a 2d vector using a 1d index

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, vector, iterator

Given a vector of vector of int (for example), the following piece of code allows me to map the flat position into a 2d index and access the element:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, acc = 0;

while ((acc = myVector[x].size()+acc) <= position) {
     x++;
     y= acc;
}
y = position - y;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to iterate over all the elements of my 2d vector using a single pointer thus incrementing it by the position number.

EDIT1:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector;

myVector.emplace_back();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myVector[0].emplace_back(0);
}

myVector.emplace_back();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myVector[0].emplace_back(1);
}

myVector.emplace_back();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    myVector[0].emplace_back(2);
}

for (auto row : myVector) {
    for (auto col : row) {
        std::cout << col << std::endl;
    }
}
```

What I need is to create a pointer to the first element pointed by `myVector[0][0]` and then create a link between the end of the first row and the beginning of the next one so I can iterate over it using a single pointer.
If I need the element at position 12 then just by incrementing the pointer I can get the element in position (1,1).
Basically I'm trying to emulate the behaviour of the c arrays using std::vectors

Comment: Please make a [mre] and show some examples of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: For what do you need that? Why do you have a 2D vector if you use it as 1D flat vector? In one week(or one hour later) you and nobody else will understand this piece of code...

Comment: Such is possible in C-styled arrays, since they are directly stored next to each other in memory. By using classes, such as `std::vector`, other member variables like the length are being stored, so between each subvector of the main vector, there will be stuff you don't want to iterate over.

Comment: Antonio, Blayer answered you good solution. Your desire with pointer has a trouble: vectors can change memory block after modification (you shouldn't use fixed pointers). And those links of pointers you should store somewhere.

Comment: *"I'm trying to emulate the behaviour of the c arrays"* -- There is a key difference in behavior, though. Your vectors are not guaranteed to be the same length, whereas a 2D array would have to have uniform lengths in the minor dimension. For a more complicated situation, you should expect a more complicated solution.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to implement it the other way around? Use a "1D" vector and map 2D indices into a 1D index.

Answer (score 0):

In c++20, there is direct support for this functionality using the `<ranges>` header. So you could simply do:

```
namespace srv = std::ranges::views;

for (auto i : myVector | srv::join)
     std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3dK866).

With range-v3, you can make a `vector` of the joined view like this:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;
    
auto j = myVector | rv::join | ranges::to<std::vector<int>>;
```

and then index into it arbitrary positions.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Geqxhv).

Comment: I need a pointer that allows me to random access to myVector also by linking the end of each row vector

Comment: If you use range-v3, you can use `ranges::to<>` after joining, and you can use random access on that joined container.

Comment: @AntonioSantoro do you absolutely need random access? or would [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) suffice? You will need to walk the outer vector counting the sizes of the inner vectors to know which vector contains the element you are seeking.

Comment: @AntonioSantoro Added a demo for random access. But this creates a new vector, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own container class which does the following:

1. Take a vector of vectors as the constructor argument.  Store the vector of vectors address as its member.
2. implement get(size_t p) to iterate through like below:

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < v.size() && p > v[i].size(); i++)
{
   p -= v[i].size();
}
return v[i][p];
```

3. overload [] to point to get

Comment: if with "rectangular" you mean that each row need to be the same length then that is not my case

Comment: Edited to allow non-rectangular, at the cost of efficiency/speed.

Comment: Your proposed `get()` is essentially the same as the function in the question. Instead of adding sizes, then subtracting the sum from the position, you subtract each size from the position. I find your version clearer to read, but it's still the approach that the question seeks to replace.

Comment: Yes it has degenerated to that... I don't think there's a better solution if non-rectangular shapes AND future edits must be accommodated for.  Remember, a 2D C array (which was what was mentioned in the ORIGINAL question), will always be 1: rectangular, 2. not changing in size post-allocation.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is a way to iterate over all the elements of my 2d vector using a single pointer

**No**, there isn't. You can't assume the elements of the first vector are followed by the elements of the second vector, etc.

You can instead use a `std::vector<int>` to store all you elements contiguously, then construct a `std::vector<std::span<int>>` as a "2d" view of those elements

```
std::vector<int> raw;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    raw.emplace_back(0);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    raw.emplace_back(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    raw.emplace_back(2);
}

std::vector<std::span<int>> myVector;
myVector.emplace_back(raw.data(), 10);
myVector.emplace_back(raw.data() + 10, 5);
myVector.emplace_back(raw.data() + 15, 8);

for (auto row : myVector) {
    for (auto col : row) {
        std::cout << col << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/d7G9jM)

Comment: if a std::vector stores the element [contiguously](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and contains std::vectors, why isn't guaranteed that all the elements are contiguously and at the end of the first std::vector (row) starts the second contained one?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro Because there's *no* guarantee that the elements of the second vector are stored *immediately after* the elements of the first. You could consider (the actual implementation may be quite different) a vector as a class that stores a pointer to the elements along with the size and the capacity. In a vector of vectors, those are the data contiguously laied out.

Comment: @AntonioSantoro Because the contiguous thing is the { pointer-to-data, size, capacity } (or equivalent) data members of the vector. Each vector has allocated some dynamic storage for it's elements. A vector of vectors in general *can't* coordinate the inner vector allocations to be contiguous, because you might add elements into the middle. The standard doesn't permit invalidating iterators of *some other* vector when you add elements to another.

Comment: now it's clear thank you. is there a stl container with dynamic size to get what I need?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro *all* types have a static size. If you want contiguous elements, use a 1d vector